# JS performance issue with on hover tooltip

Tags: javascript, performance, tooltip

I have the following code which displays a tooltip in the same location as the mouse pointer hovers. While I'm able to get the tooltip to display and follow the mouse the performance is really bad. When I say bad performance I mean that it is laggy, the tooltip struggles to keep up with the mouse. Please test in snippet.

Why is the performance so bad and is there a better way to do this?

```js
const tileContainer = document.querySelector('.tile-container');
     

// Create a new div element
var tooltipDiv = document.createElement('div');

// Set the class and id attributes for the div
tooltipDiv.className = 'test-toolTip';
tooltipDiv.id = 'tooltip';

// Get the element with the id 'TileArea'
var tileArea = document.getElementById('TileArea');

// Append the new div to the 'TileArea' element
tileArea.appendChild(tooltipDiv);
const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');


const tile = document.createElement('div');
tile.classList.add('tile');
tile.innerHTML = `
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>data</p>
    `;
    
    
tile.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  tooltip.innerText = `title : data`;
  tooltip.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
  tooltip.style.display = 'inline-block';
});

tileContainer.appendChild(tile);
```

```css
.tile-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile {
    /* width: calc(33.33% - 10px); */
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test-toolTip
{
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  max-width: 130px;   /*max width for large numbers*/
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(69, 69, 69);
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tile-container" id="TileArea">
        <!-- Dynamic tiles will be inserted here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) event to move the Tooltip.

This event does not trigger as much as you'd like to reflect a smooth movement of the mouse.

Once the `mouseover` is triggered, you should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to listen to the [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) event, when you use this to move the Tooltip, it will be smooth.

Don't forget to call [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) on [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) to remove the event.

```js
const tileContainer = document.querySelector('.tile-container');

var tooltipDiv = document.createElement('div');
tooltipDiv.className = 'test-toolTip';
tooltipDiv.id = 'tooltip';

var tileArea = document.getElementById('TileArea');
tileArea.appendChild(tooltipDiv);

const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

const tile = document.createElement('div');
tile.classList.add('tile');
tile.innerHTML = `
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>data</p>
`;

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    tooltip.innerText = `title : data`;
    tooltip.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    tooltip.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    tooltip.style.display = 'inline-block';
}

tile.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
});

tile.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
});

tileContainer.appendChild(tile);
```

```css
.tile-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile {
    /* width: calc(33.33% - 10px); */
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test-toolTip
{
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  max-width: 130px;   /*max width for large numbers*/
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(69, 69, 69);
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-container" id="TileArea">
    <!-- Dynamic tiles will be inserted here -->
</div>
```